# ORA-00907: falta el paréntesis derecho al crear tabla

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-18c

Estoy tratando de crear una tabla en mi base de datos para simular una aplicación. El tema es que me lanza el error

> *ORA-00907: falta el paréntesis derecho*

y no sé por qué se produce (claramente menciona el paréntesis derecho, pero según yo sí está dicho paréntesis). Lo que quiero lograr, es que el atributo *id_juego* vaya incrementando automáticamente. Les comento que estoy trabajando en Oracle 18c XE.
Les presento el código a continuación:

```sql
CREATE TABLE BIBLIOTECA(
        id_game INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('serial'),
        rank INTEGER NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde la versión 12c Oracle cambió la forma de generar este tipo de columnas.

Ahora debes usar:

```
GENERATED [ ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT [ ON NULL ] ]
AS IDENTITY [ ( identity_options ) ]
```

En tu caso, con esto debería funcionar:

```
CREATE TABLE BIBLIOTECA(
        id_game INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1),
        rank INTEGER NOT NULL,
        name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
    );
```

Si quieres otro tipo de opciones, puedes cambiarlas libremente.

Para más detalles, consulta [este tutorial](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-identity-column/) o consulta directamente la [documentación de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/other-databases/nosql-database/21.2/sqlreferencefornosql/identity-column.html).

---

#### Fiddle

> ```
> CREATE TABLE BIBLIOTECA(
>         id_game INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1),
>         rank INTEGER NOT NULL,
>         name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
>     );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO BIBLIOTECA  (rank, name) VALUES (10,'name 10');
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO BIBLIOTECA  (rank, name) VALUES (20,'name 20');
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO BIBLIOTECA  (rank, name) VALUES (30,'name 30');
> ```

> 

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM BIBLIOTECA;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID_GAME | RANK | NAME   
> ------: | ---: | :------
>       1 |   10 | name 10
>       2 |   20 | name 20
>       3 |   30 | name 30
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c78c1e03bc1fdc42adec23fcd92c68b6)*